# Problems with text file output in PDI Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I need help with this trouble. 
In a transformation I create a text file delimited by semicolons from a table input, but when I look at the file, this shows me empty lines.

this is the transform I made: options in  text file output

[image]

And this is the result: text file result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the `Fields` tab of the Text File Output step, make `Trim Type = both` for all the fields. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thnx for answer, but i put that configuration in the text file output step and the output is the same.

Comment: the solution was make a function for delete the special characters, maybe some texts come with line jump or something. I appreciate the help. regards!

Answer (score 0):

Column8 seems to contain linebreaks.  If the next consumer of your output CSV file is able to deal with linebreaks in text fields, enable option "Force the enclosure around fields", else you'll have to decide on whether you remove or replace those special characters which can be done on the server using SQL or on the client using a Replace-In-String step, for example.

Comment: I try this, but the result is the same. Maybe was because i have 2 fields with CLOB type. Thanx for answer btw :)

Comment: the solution was make a function for delete the special characters, maybe some texts come with line jump or something. I appreciate the help. regards!